# PHP format number without using number_format function

Tags: php

AS the title says: using this number `1000000.125685`, how can I format it like `1,000,000.125` without using `number_function`, since that function rounds the decimals?

```
number_format("1000000.125685",3) //returns 1,000,000.126
```

How can I give whatever number I want 'Money Format' without using `number_format`?

Comment: I think most of the math/string functions will round a number. You may need to use math ( number * 100, floor(), /100) to get the number you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use [`floor()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.floor.php) on the number prior to formatting it, this will get what you want.  The problem is that `floor()` rounds fractions and not 'to n decimal places'.  So this code does the round trip of *1000 and then /1000...

```
echo number_format(floor(1000000.125685*1000)/1000,3);
```

gives...

```
1,000,000.125
```

To wrap this up into a function with the number and decimal places as parameters...

```
function number_format2( float $n, int $dp ): string {
    $multi = pow(10, $dp);
    return number_format(floor($n*$multi)/$multi,$dp);
}
echo number_format2(1000000.125685,4);
```

Comment: but if I have n numbers of decimals?

Comment: I've added a function to wrap that up into the code. (depending on version of PHP - you may have to remove type hinting)