# number_format changes decimal digits

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I want to work with DECIMAL(18,9) numbers from MySQL. In Laravel Eloquent there is a decimal cast that works internally with the number_format function, so that you end up with a string that you can then use for bcMath functions.
I wonder why the number_format function produces such an error? Actually, the input is intended for floating point numbers, but then it should generally only work with 5 decimal places for such a large number.

Is there a safe alternative to number_format that works with any number of decimal places as input?

```
$x = "123456789.123456789";
$y = number_format($x, 9, '.', '');
$z = (double)$x;

print $x . "\n";
print $y . "\n";
print $z . "\n";

Output (PHP 8.1.17):
123456789.123456789
123456789.123456791
123456789.12346
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: @DarkBee The final question is if there is a safe alternative to "number_format" for decimal numbers.

Comment: This could be [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56262124/php-format-number-without-using-number-format-function)

Comment: Enter your number in https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html and you'll see floats just don't have enough precision.

Comment: I can't provide an answer since I don't know Laravel but you need a data type that handles data as string all the way through. Eloquent does not seem to have such type,  you need a custom type (I assume it's possible to do that).

Comment: [bcmul](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.bcmul.php) can be alternative to number_format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to work with precise decimal numbers, especially in the context of financial calculations, it's better to use a library like BCMath, which allows arbitrary precision arithmetic. Here's an example using BCMath for your case:

```
$x = "123456789.123456789";

// Use BCMath to maintain precision
$y = bcadd($x, "0", 9); // 0 specifies the scale (number of decimal places)

// Convert the result to a double if needed
$z = (double)$y;

print $x . "\n";
print $y . "\n";
print $z . "\n";
```

**Note** : Ensure that the bcmath extension is enabled in your PHP configuration. If it's not enabled, you can enable it in your php.ini file or by installing the bcmath extension.

```
extension=bcmath
```

Comment: I think you've answered the question tittle but not the question itself. OP is using a framework and the framework itself converts the string supplied by database driver into float. You've already lost precision right at the start, so there's nothing that bcmath can fix afterwards.

Comment: Nice trick! I already use BCMath for calculations and it's possible to build own Cast-Functions in Laravel.

Comment: @root66 You could post an answer using these `Cast-Functions` in order to create a more Laravel-focused solution